# Launching Tensorflow : Cannot import name PROJECTOR_FILENAME

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, tensorboard

So when I try to launch tensorboard I got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/tensorboard", line 7, in <module>
    from tensorflow.tensorboard.tensorboard import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/tensorboard.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tensorflow.tensorboard.backend import server
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/backend/server.py", line 38, in <module>
    from tensorflow.tensorboard.plugins.projector import plugin as projector_plugin
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/plugins/projector/plugin.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins.projector import PROJECTOR_FILENAME
ImportError: cannot import name PROJECTOR_FILENAME
```

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I've got this error when I've used following command to launch TB:

```
python -m tensorflow.tensorboard
```

When I've used another one it went ok:

```
tensorboard --logdir=path/to/log-directory
```